# Need clarification to understand quotient space

Tags: algebraic-topology

While studying quotient topology, I have learnt that quotient space can be obtain from a topological space and an equivalence relation(which provides the identification of points in the space). So if you are given an topological space and an equivalence relation then the so called quotient space obtain must be unique. But the equivalence relation only provide which points you have to identify, do not provide the direction or how you can identify. As an example, if you are given an rectangular piece of paper and have to identify its two width in same direction , then you can glue two width without any twist or you can add 1 full twist (half (1/2) twist forms Mobius strip) to it and then glue, you have to get same quotient space, i.e. the two space obtain must be homeomorphic, but I can not calculate the homeomorphism , Is it so obvious or need some calculation.  Again for make our life harder, we can self intersect the rectangle and then glue it from the opposite site(I think it can be understand ), Then I have no idea to call it same quotient space with previous two. But, thinking about the interpretation of visualizing Klein's Bottle in R^4, to avoid the self intersection, I think the last quotient space will be same with previous two in R^4. But I have no confidence with my argument, I need some help to understand this and what is it meant to be same as topological space, can it be same in higher dimension but not same in lower dimension , then also we called those same topological space?

Comment: The two gluings of the rectangle that you described (untwisted and $1$ full twist) produce the same space. The difference between them is how they are embedded in the bigger space $\mathbb R^3$. And the concept of quotient space says nothing about embeddings (or immersions as in your later self-intersecting example).

Comment: so , the third type is also same?

Comment: You seem to be asking the question "What are the elements of the quotient space?", which has a simple abstract answer: an element is an equivalence class. This leads me to believe that's not what you are actually asking. Perhaps you  are asking how to visualize quotient spaces?

Comment: Anyway, your question could use some focus. It is kind of all over the place, making it difficult to figure out exactly what you are asking and what kind of answer would be satisfying to you. Perhaps you could edit your question to make it more restricted, maybe more focussed on one particular example.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the equivalence relation tells you how to identify points, meaning this relation alone only tells you what the resulting *set* will be. In order to uniquely (up to homeomorphism) define your quotient space, you also need to impose a certain topology related to your equivalence relation. This is precisely the purpose of the quotient topology. This topology identifies open sets in your quotient space with open sets in the preimage, and it is this topology which connects your new space with the equivalence relation used to produce it. If instead we took the new quotient *set* and imposed an arbitrary topology on it, yes, there would be a few different "directions" or "ways of identifying" your points.

tl;dr The equivalence relation only gives you a quotient *set*, and in order to make the resulting *space* unique up to homeomorphism, we impose the quotient topology on the set.